# how to get return value from webview.executeJavaScript in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, preload

hi all in my project i have three js files, **main.js**,**browser.js** and **inject.js**, in **browser.js** i have implemented all the click action related to my webview and many functionalities, from this i have a click action to get Username from the webpage which is loaded in webview for that i created a function in **inject.js** to get contents and elements from the page i got the value in **Inject.js** files but in **Browser.js** files i getting undefined values

**here my sample code:**

> browser.js

```
var proName = webview.executeJavaScript('__myInjection.profileName()');
```

> inject.js

```
profileName : function (){
var recordArray = []
var url
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = require('./jquery-3.2.1.min.js');

  $(document).ready(function() {
 url = $("[data-control-name='identity_profile_photo']").attr("href");
alert(url)
  });

return url;


},
```

values getting called in inject.js but browser.js returns **Undefined** values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not exactly sure why you resort to inject JS code into a WebView, but why not… Make sure it is not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

1. [`webview.executeJavascript()`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#webviewexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback) method does not return anything. You can pass a *callback* as 3rd argument (more on that below), but I do not think it receives anything from the executed code.
2. In your injected code, you create a callback that will get executed on page ready. Therefore anything returned by your function (like your `url` variable) will not have been affected yet by the callback code. Make sure you understand [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

If I understand correctly, you are trying to scrap some data on your embedded page, and send it back to your Renderer (browser).

A more appropriate way of achieving this result would be to use the [`preload`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#preload) attribute of electron `<webview>`:

```html
<webview src="urlToGuestPage" preload="./inject.js"></webview>
```

In `inject.js`, you can `require(electron)`, and use the electron IPC scheme (`electron.ipcRenderer`) to communicate between the `Webview` ([`ipcRendrer.sendToHost()`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/#ipcrenderersendtohostchannel-arg1-arg2-)) and the "parent" Renderer. You have a simple example there: https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#event-ipc-message

```js
// In embedder page. (parent Renderer / browser.js)
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')
webview.addEventListener('ipc-message', (event) => {
  console.log(event.channel)
  // Prints "pong"
})
webview.send('ping')

// In guest page. (preload script for the webview / inject.js)
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
ipcRenderer.on('ping', () => {
  ipcRenderer.sendToHost('pong')
})
```

You should be able to find more detailed tutorials for such communication between a Renderer and a webview, e.g. https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/201/how-to-send-retrieve-information-and-manipulate-the-dom-from-a-webview-with-electron-framework

Answer (score 0):

it can return as Promise and able to catch.

```
var _script = `Promise.resolve({t:'XXX'})`;
const wView = document.querySelector('#wView');
wView.executeJavaScript(_script)
.then(resExec=> console.log(resExec))
.catch(errExec=> console.log('ERROR', errExec));
```